# What is the answer of this math puzzle?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

One of my friend brought this simple-looking math puzzle to me, but it was harder than it seems.
I tried several ideas including simple arithmetic operations, and even considering base-n.

```
5#2=18 
8#2=11 
7#4=45
3#5=33 
6#3=?
```

The ?(answer) must be an integer.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=5a%2B2b%2B10c%2Bd%3D18+%3B+8a%2B2b%2B16c%2Bd%3D11++%3B+7a%2B4b%2B28c%2Bd%3D45++%3B+3a%2B5b%2B15c%2Bd%3D33

Comment: @msh210 You're a 10k-er, why would you comment something like that?

Comment: @Bass I don't understand your question.

Comment: @msh210 Surely you must realise that if you introduce two new unknown variables with whichever factors, you can always (rules and restrictions may apply, check your algebra book for details) solve the equation set and get a result that is completely dependent on the factors you chose and has nothing at all to do with the original question.

Comment: @Bass "has nothing to do with the original equation" is a bit much. The solution offered at my link above is in fact a solution to this puzzle. (Certainly not the only one, though: as you point out, it depends on the form of the equations I made up.)

Comment: @msh210 Let's recap: you made up a way to add arbitrary stuff to the problem, and then proceeded to solve it for a result that is completely dependent on said arbitrary stuff, and posted a link to that result. One of the few things that's known for certain about that result is that it is never going to be the one unique solution to the question as posted by OP. This, then, brings us to my original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146658/discussion-between-msh210-and-bass).

Comment: @msh210 Very nice observation. Bass he used a minimal number of variables. He did not attempt to do it with 5 or more variables.

Comment: @Moti the problem is, that minimal number was four. With four variables, you can "solve" absolutely anything with four given data points. If the solution were "If you replace these numbers with A-Z = 1-26, you get rude words in Lithuanian", you could still apply msh210's method, and get some number as a result. And that result would be just as meaningful as the result here.

Comment: *And the answer should be a clear integer in a same sense.* Are you sure about that? If you are that is important information that belongs in the question body. My natural assumption would be looking for an operation instead

Comment: @xyldke edited, thanks!

Comment: I think xyldke was talking about the #, but I assume you mean that the ? must be an integer.

Comment: @Bass But getting the exact values in the puzzle means that this is a solution to the puzzle - the task here was to find this fit! mas210 was successful in SOLVING the puzzle (what is the probability to get this?)

Comment: @Moti You are completely missing the point. If you get four data points, you can find an infinite number of different functions that match exactly those values at exactly those four points. msh210 chose one of those functions, without any justification why that function should be chosen rather than any other, and then calculated the value of that function at the fifth point. That is not finding a solution, it is saying "Look ma, I drew a line through all the numbers in this colour-by-numbers puzzle".

Comment: @SinonOW I think your friend is just making stuff up. One of my friends did the same thing, back when we were in grade school. Wrote a bunch of equations like this using the `#` symbol, and said the symbol was something "she learned from her sister, who is in a higher level math class".

Comment: @SinonOW Apparently, somebody else asked the identical question already, and there seems to be an answer. https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/answer-math-puzzle-5-2-18-8-2-11-7-4-45-3-5-33-6-3-q116235393

Comment: @theozh it's an upload from me, and it was a chatGPT answer where the calculation wasn't even correct.

Comment: @codewarrior0 I doubt it, because this was supposed to be a bonus question that was given in a proper test by a professor. But I'm also thinking about the possibility that this is a nonsense question.

Comment: @Bass There is exactly one like this one - the NICE thing about his solution is that he, knowing that there is only one system of 4 that could be a possible solution to the puzzle. If there is another system of 4 to result in such coefficients in the RIGHT order, would love to see Bass.

Comment: @Moti Well, since you asked nicely, I'll humour you. Try plugging in the left-hand side values into $$\frac{1040}{9}x + \frac{89}{6}y - \frac{7391}{378}xy - \frac{29780}{189}\frac{x}{y}$$ and see what happens. Then try $$ -\frac{223}{78}x^2 + \frac{209}{6}x + \frac{506}{39}y - \frac{4315}{39}$$These both use 4 coefficients, both fit the given data exactly, and both will of course give wildly different values for x=6,y=3 (70-something and 34-something, respectively).

Comment: @SinonOW Would knowing the subject be relevant to the problem? Ex. we might be looking for a number theory answer vs a calculus answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I feel like this problem is underspecified, even if constrained by an obligation to find something terse (a point being made in the comments, I think).

For example, suppose we had a code phrase of "A CRY OF THE CRYPTOGRAPHER" (or in fact any phrase starting with "A CRY OF TH", and n#m meant to find the $n$th and $m$th letter (in "ACRYOFTHECRYPTOGRAPHER"), then translate them to numbers with $a=1, b=2, \ldots, z=26$, and finally add them up. That takes a while to write out, but is still pretty occam if I can shamelessly verb that (ugh, amiright?)

Anyway, that gives:

\begin{eqnarray}
5\#2&\rightarrow O,C \rightarrow 15+3 =& 18\\
8\#2&\rightarrow H,C \rightarrow 8+3 =& 11\\
7\#4&\rightarrow T,Y \rightarrow 20+25 =& 45\\
3\#5&\rightarrow R,O \rightarrow 18+15 =& 33
\end{eqnarray}

So the answer is (okay, I'll put in a spoiler, but I can't believe that's what this is):

> $6\#3\rightarrow F,R \rightarrow 6+18 = 24$

A little more on generating this solution (such as it is).

We have 2 small digits on the left, both less than 8. And we have 11 to 45 on the right. This range *possibly* suggests the sum of two letters, where letters are actually numbers from 1 to 26.

If this premise is correct (and I'm not saying it is, but it's at least conceivable), then we'd be looking for 8 letters to index against. Equations 1, 2, and 4, give us 10 possibilities:

- `-ap-q--j`,
- `-bq-p--i`,
- `-cr-o--h`,
- `-ds-n--g`,
- `-et-m--f`,
- `-fu-l--e`,
- `-gv-k--d`,
- `-hw-j--c`,
- `-ix-i--b`,
- `-jy-h--a`,

Equation 3 gives us 8 more possibilities:

- `---s--z-`
- `---t--y-`
- `---u--x-`
- `---v--w-`
- `---w--v-`
- `---x--u-`
- `---y--t-`
- `---z--s-`

for a total of 80 possible templates, such as `-cryo-th`, which mixes the third of the first group (`-cr-o--h`) with the seventh of the second group (`---y--t-`). However, any of the 80 combinations would yield a valid solution. There are no one- or two-word solutions that fit (which would have been better, occam-wise I think), but there are many others that are a bit meh, but still work.

A couple of others:

- "A CRY OUT H..."
- "OF US LAZED"
- "FIX XII UBIquitously" or XIV or XIX.

The last of these translates as:

\begin{eqnarray}
5\#2&\rightarrow I,I \rightarrow 9+9 =& 18\\
8\#2&\rightarrow B,I \rightarrow 2+9 =& 11\\
7\#4&\rightarrow U,X \rightarrow 21+24 =& 45\\
3\#5&\rightarrow X,I \rightarrow 24+9 =& 33\\
6\#3&\rightarrow I,X \rightarrow 9+24 =& 33\\
\end{eqnarray}

Coincidentally, the same answer. "FIX XIX UBI" would have given us 48. Should I find one that gives an answer of 42?