# What does this mathematical operator do?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

The solution to this puzzle is one I came up with when working on this puzzle: [What is the answer of this math puzzle?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121174/what-is-the-answer-of-this-math-puzzle)

For two natural numbers `a,b`, can you figure out how `a#b` is defined, going from the following examples?

```
2#0 = 10
2#2 = 2
2#16 = 8
3#3 = 3
4#9 = 3
5#5 = 5
5#11 = 7
5#17 = 9
6#13 = 7
9#12 = 12
9#16 = 16
10#3 = 7
```

Following this rule, work out `3#19`.

---

This is a mathematical puzzle, i.e., all numbers actually represent numbers and not letters of the alphabet. Also for the input the numerical value of the inputs and their representation (i.e., the base in which they are writen in) are relevant, not the number of holes, its English name or anything like that. Programming and similar technical help can help, but is not required.

---

If it takes a while until it is solved, I would like to make this puzzle a bit more interactive. Instead of (or in addition to) giving hints, I will provide more examples on some of your suggested inputs that you think will help you find the pattern.

---

Hint #1:

> `8#8=2`

> `13#13=19`

Hint #2:

> `9#4=2`

Hint #3:

> `3#0=10`

> `4#0=10`

Hint #4:

> `0#6=2`

> `0#7=3`

Hint #5:

> `a#b` is always valid. However, there *may* be cases where one could argue it is a bit ambiguous. I haven't seen such cases yet, but also couldn't rule out that they exist.

Hint #6:

> `1000#1000=3000`

Hint #7:

> While it should be possible to write `a#b` as a single function, it is much easier and more intuitive to think of it as a procedure that takes the inputs and performs some algorithmic steps.

Hint #8:

> `0#5=5`

> `0#8=2`

> `0#12=4`

Hint #9:

> `5#23=3`

> `5#31=3`

Hint #10:

> There are no explicit "magic constants" involved (e.g., divide by 3). Someone mathematically interested might however argue that there is one implicit constant involved.

Hint #11:

> `0x2#0x2=2`

> `0xF#0xF=3`, however `15#15=5` (which should clarify the last hint)

Hint #12:

> Hint #5, that `a#b` is always valid, was meant for base 10 when I added it. Now with people exploring other bases I should say that there is one base for which `a#b` may not be valid. In fact (if a certain conjecture holds) there are infinitely many inputs for which `a#b` is undefined in that base. As far as I can tell (no guarantees on this) in other bases `a#b` is always valid.

Hint #13:

> The operator utilizes concatenation.

Hint #14:

> 0#0=2

Comment: It feels like rot13(rkcbaragf ner vaibyirq). Also, is it always true that rot13(ehaavat gur bcrengvba jvgu gur fnzr k ba obgu fvqrf ergheaf k)?

Comment: I have the same questions as Someone, but also ROT13(Vf vg pbzzhgngvir? Va bgure jbeqf, qbrf n # o rdhny o # n)

Comment: This would be a hint, so your call when or whether to tell us: Is it always true that a#b=b#a?

Comment: the `#` is the function `f(x, y) = -0.2679x² + 0.0536y² + 0.6429x - 0.4286y + 11.2857` and the value of 3#19 is approximately 2.7. (note, this should not be taken seriously)

Comment: Added some hints. @Marius Actually I would have been quite impressed to see the 12 data points happen to fit on a quadratic ;)

Comment: Could we see another number # by 0? Say, 3#0?

Comment: What happens if $a=0$?

Comment: Is $a\#b$ valid for all integers $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Any chance we can see something wacky, like 1000#1000?

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic my bet is on `1000#1000 = 1000`, but I could be wrong

Comment: I feel like I see a pattern of primes but not sure. Is a#a **always** a prime?

Comment: @Marius Could be. I'm just curious because 2#2 = 2, 3#3 = 3, 5#5 = 5, but suddenly 13#13 = 19?

I'm wondering if there's some wacky modulo stuff happening.

Comment: I've added Dr Xorile's questions for now and will add the others later or tomorrow.

Comment: the only striking thing for me (so far) is rot13(vs o vf bqq (be rira) gur erfhyg vf nf jryy.). But maybe there will be counter examples in the future?

Comment: New hints are really useful. I might take a proper programmatic crack at this tonight. I'm curious if you can reveal this in a hint, but I wanted to know; does the underlying algorithm involve any hidden coefficients/constants? Say, "divide b by 3"? Or are the only two values at play "a" and "b", transforming one another?

Comment: I deduce that 5#23=11... Can I get the value for 5#23 and 5#31?

Comment: I'd like to see a counter-example of "0#b is a prime". Or to get value of 0#5 and 0#8...

Comment: Related to theozh's observation, rot13(o vf qvivfvoyr ol svir vss gur erfhyg vf nyfb (cerivbhf bofreingvba, gur fnzr vf gehr sbe gjb))

Comment: Anyone getting anywhere on this? I wonder if hint #10 is perhaps about a rot13(Svobanppv frdhrapr naq gur tbyqra engvb). It might be nice to get some values for a fixed a or b, maybe even 1#b and a#1 for a few cases.

Comment: @ChrisLewis I was thinking that the "implicit constant"could be rot13(ybtnevguz, nf ybt jbhyq or vzcyvpvgyl onfr-10, be ya jbhyq or vzcyvpvgyl onfr-r, gubfr ner uvqqra pbafgnagf)

Comment: I haven't made any good progress. For what it's worth, my suspicion is also that the implied constant is rot13(gur enqvk/onfr bs gur ahzore flfgrz, juvpu nccrnef gb or onfr 10. guvf pbhyq or zvfyrnqvat gubhtu.)

On that note, OP, here's a hint request; can you do 0xF#0xF for us? Possibly 0x2#0x2 also?

Comment: Added two more hints. Originally I did not mean for the input to be in other bases but it extends pretty naturally and I think it may actually help quite a bit in figuring it out.

Comment: My brain might be about to authentically melt out of my ears.

Comment: Concanetation? This would be a big clue!

Comment: I think that'll help: rot5(75, 77, 751, 88, 94, 00, 066, 062, 169, 467, 461, 658).

Comment: The operands can't be in any base at all if the operands are natural numbers. The operands would have to be *written numbers* for the base to matter. Did you mean that the base is a third operand to the operator?

Comment: Can you provide the result for 0#0 ?

Comment: @codewarrior0 Yes, the base can be seen as a third input. At first I implicitly used base 10 and did not think about other bases. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Can you submit your function to [The Devil's Calculator](https://github.com/cinqmarsmedia/The-Devils-Calculator-A-Math-Puzzle-Game) so that we can try it interactively?

Comment: Can you provide the result for 52#3 and 53#1?