# One more "What does this operator do" question

Tags: mathematics, pattern

it is fun to observe that questions like this [What does this mathematical operator do?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121215/what-does-this-mathematical-operator-do) raise more new questions than correct answers!

When trying to solve the original question, I came to this new operator:

```
0#1 = 32
1#1 = 1
1#2 = 3
1#3 = 37
2#1 = 6
3#1 = 9
5#1 = 4
7#1 = 13
```

By default we consider that:

> `For each natural a:  a#0 = 0`

One useful hint

> `For each naturals a,b: a#(b+1) > a#b`

No complex algorithm here! The answer should not be longer than a 10 to 12-words sentence like "a#b is the ..."

Enjoy solving this. I can provide some extra hints if needed...

Comment: Can you provide more examples where b>1? Maybe some where a or b > 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of `a#b` is

> the position of the $b$-th occurrence of $a$ in the decimals of $\pi$. You can check here: $\pi = $ `3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651...`

But shouldn't `a#0` then perhaps be `NaN` instead of `0`?

To @Lezzup's question: I derive from the principle above that `1#10 = 110` and accordingly `10#1 = 49`.

Comment: Well done! I agree with your comments and examples. I initially planned to disclose as an extra hint (if puzzle was not solved so fast!) the value of 15#1 and 159#1 to ring a bell...